# How to set current month, day or year as workflow parameter in a coordinator (on Hue)

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I have a Oozie workflow which has three parameters that expect a day, month and year respectively. This workflow works perfect with manual input. I am now looking for a coordinator which daily runs this workflow and automatically fills in these parameters with the current day, month and year.

I already tried `${DAY}`, `${MONTH}` and `${YEAR}` which Hue seemed to propose but I get the following error when submitting the coordinator with e.g. `${MONTH}` as value for my month parameter.

```
E1004: Expression language evaluation error, Unable to evaluate :${MONTH}:
```

I am trying this on CDH 5.8.

Comment: @YoungHobbit I don't understand your question. My coordinator is attached to the workflow and in its configuration I try to fill in the workflow parameters. Other than that this coordinator is set to run each day. In Hue I can't really change a lot more than that.

Comment: In Hue every coordinator needs to have one workflow which you can select under "Which workflow to schedule?". So that is how they are connected. Then it automatically asks to fill in the workflow's parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself with something Hue also suggested to me.
So `${DAY}`, `${MONTH}` and `${YEAR}` were not the way to go.

The following values however did solve my question:

```
${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(),'dd')}

${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(),'MM')}

${coord:formatTime(coord:nominalTime(),'yyyy')}
```